Do I need to raise my hands for saying the dua in Salah?
How to make dua before tasleem in Salah? In what position should I be to say my dua? Should I raise my hands or should I simply be in a sitting position?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the StackExchange model consider taking the tour] and checking our [help].

You recite the dua while sitting, without raising your hands. The same way you that you recite salawat (durood).
