How to make dua before tasleem
Assalamu alaikum,I have heard from scholars that we can make our own dua in sujood and before tasleem.
But i have a doubt how to make my own dua before tasleem (in tashahhud).i have some doubts like,
Do i need to raise my hands or make my own dua in sitting position.
Do i need keep my finger pointed when making my own dua like in attahiyyat,durood etc.
please answer. It will really help a lot.so i can make my salah more mistakes free.
May Allah Bless You.

Ask one question per post. Also read the answer to your previous question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/85633/ Please learn the method of performing salah from another person or a video tutorial.
